# JTextfield UML Class Diagram

Tags: java, uml, jtextfield, class-diagram, object-oriented-analysis

I'm having 2 classes for a specific purpose in my project, basically what I am doing is putting everything related to GUI in let's say Class 1 and functionality and data manipulations in Class 2.

Class 2 will contain member variables such as int, String represented on class diagram. However for Class 1, I have member variables of type JTextfield, JCombobox, among others which are normally used in a GUI.

My question is : Do we usually show member variables such as JTextfield on the class diagram?

Answer (score 0):

*Do we usually show member variables such as JTextfield on the class diagram?*

No

Only  variables are need to be mentioned in the class diagram.

For the specifications of the variable, create one more file (Known as UISpecification) and there mention the type of your variable like

```
Variable   Type

Str         Text
```

Usually this UISpecification file is made in XL sheet

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: it depends. Namely on the target group of the diagram.

- For an overview you can completely suppress the properties compartment.
- For a more general use you can choose to show just public properties.
- And for a detailed (implementation) view you can create a diagram that shows private properties also.